# How do I find the Hive database that uses a given HDFS path?

Tags: hive, hdfs

I have an hdfs path, and I know that there's a Hive database that uses this path. How can find which database it is?

I can write a script that will list all the databases and describe them, and grep for the path, but I'm guessing/hoping there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to backend RDBMS system used to store hive metadata then you can query the data directly using sql.

Example:

```
select * from DBS where DB_LOCATION_URI like '%location1%'
```

To know the exact schema of the metadata check the source code based on version of your hive [here](https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/metastore/scripts/upgrade/mysql).